# react-native-git-upgrade Error: Cannot find module 'AccessibilityInfo'

Tags: react-native

Environment

```
System:
OS: macOS 10.14.2
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4578U CPU @ 3.00GHz
Memory: 448.52 MB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
Node: 11.6.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin/node
npm: 6.7.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: iOS 12.1, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.1, watchOS 5.1
Android SDK:
API Levels: 26, 27, 28
Build Tools: 27.0.3, 28.0.3
System Images: android-24 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-26 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
IDEs:
Android Studio: 3.3 AI-182.5107.16.33.5199772
Xcode: 10.1/10B61 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
react: 16.6.3 => 16.6.3
react-native: 0.57.8 => 0.57.8
npmGlobalPackages:
react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7
```

Description

step 1.
Create a new project with RN version 0.57.8.

step 2.
rename `.babelrc` to other name (.abelrc)

step 3.
react-native-git-upgrade

step 4.
rename `.abelrc` to `.babelrc`

step 5.
react-native run-ios

then terminal print the message:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './bundle/unbundle'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/morton.hsu/ReactNativeProject/testup/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/commands.js:44:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)
    at Module._compile (/Users/morton.hsu/ReactNativeProject/testup/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:83:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.newLoader (/Users/morton.hsu/ReactNativeProject/testup/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:88:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
mortonde-Mini:testup morton.hsu$ react-native info
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './bundle/unbundle'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/morton.hsu/ReactNativeProject/testup/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/commands.js:44:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)
    at Module._compile (/Users/morton.hsu/ReactNativeProject/testup/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:83:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Object.newLoader (/Users/morton.hsu/ReactNativeProject/testup/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:88:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
```

If I just create a new project with 0.58.3 or 0.57.8 is working.

But use react-native-git-upgrade from 0.57.8 to 0.58.3 and run the project get the error.

Any idea ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had same issue yesterday.

I fixed it manually.

from below files.

```
\node_modules\.cache\@babel\register\.babel.7.2.2.development.json
\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\.cache\@babel\register\.babel.7.2.2.development.json
```

Please remove

```
require('./bundle/unbundle'),
```

and `react-native run-ios`

You will get a good result.

Comment: Thanks for help, I will try it later and give the feedback.

Answer (score 7):

Other way - not so manually:

```
rm -r ./node_modules
npm cache clean --force
npm i
```

= )

Answer (score 2):

Executing

```
npm ci
```

was enough for me to fix the problem